# Device Console Errors when Installing or Running App (Debug or Release Mode)

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've noticed for a while that the iPhone app I'm developing takes a very long time to launch on a device, even though the app doesn't do much on startup (just basically shows a UIView!).

I've just thought to check the device console in the Xcode Organiser and I'm seeing lots and lots of errors when launching the app from Xcode, or from just running the app on the device without starting it from Xcode. It's occurring on both debug and release modes.

I've done a search on Google for the time out errors and it brings up 0 results, which is worrying. I have an `NSLog()` in the applications `init()` method so you can see how long it takes just to get there.

Here's the console output when I launch it:

```
Tue Nov 24 13:53:19 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:19 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:20 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:20 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:20 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:20 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:20 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:20 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 

...Shortened!

Tue Nov 24 13:53:22 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:22 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:22 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:22 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:22 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:22 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:22 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:22 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:22 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:22 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:22 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:22 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:23 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:23 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:23 unknown mobile_installationd[170] <Error>: 00808a00 install_embedded_profile: Skipping the installation of the embedded profile
Tue Nov 24 13:53:23 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:23 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:23 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:24 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:29 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:29 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:29 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:30 unknown SpringBoard[25] <Warning>: Reloading and rendering all application icons.
Tue Nov 24 13:53:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 

...Shortened!

Tue Nov 24 13:53:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:32 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:32 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:32 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:32 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:32 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:32 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:32 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:32 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:32 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:32 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:32 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:32 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:32 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:33 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:34 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: nopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:34 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:34 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:34 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:34 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:34 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:34 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:34 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:34 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:34 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:34 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:34 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:34 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85

...Shortened!

Tue Nov 24 13:53:36 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:36 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:36 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:36 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:36 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:36 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:36 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:37 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:37 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:37 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:37 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:38 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:38 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[181] <Warning>: debugserver-43 for armv6 Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Apple, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Tue Nov 24 13:53:38 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[181] <Warning>: Connecting to com.apple.debugserver service...
Tue Nov 24 13:53:39 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:39 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:40 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.mycompany.MyApplicationName[0x3761]) Spawned and waiting for the debugger to attach before continuing...
Tue Nov 24 13:53:40 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:40 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:40 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:40 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:41 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[182] Builtin profile: container (seatbelt)
Tue Nov 24 13:53:41 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[181] <Warning>: Got a connection, waiting for debugger instructions for task "(null)".
Tue Nov 24 13:53:41 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[182] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/2CC5E95A-7DFD-412F-B80C-3256698C7940 (seatbelt)
Tue Nov 24 13:53:42 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:42 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:42 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:42 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:43 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:43 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:43 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:43 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:43 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:43 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:43 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:43 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:43 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:43 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:43 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:43 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 

...Shortened!

Tue Nov 24 13:53:52 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:53 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:53 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:53 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:53 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:53 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:53 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:53 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:53 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:53 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 

...Shortened!


Tue Nov 24 13:53:54 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:54 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:54 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:54 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:54 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:54 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:55 unknown MyApplicationName[182] <Warning>: App Init Method
Tue Nov 24 13:53:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:55 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:57 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:57 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:53:57 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 

...Shortened!


Tue Nov 24 13:54:03 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:54:03 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:54:03 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:54:03 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:54:03 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:54:04 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85 
Tue Nov 24 13:54:13 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSynopsysOTGDevice::endpointInIntOccurred : TIME OUT condition detected for EP 85
```

As you can see it takes around a minute before the app launches and can be used.

This happens even when I'm not running it through XCode and it is in release mode.

I'm really struggling to find out what it is because it's causing the application's load time to be very long indeed. It also infrequently quits after it says it too too long to load.

To add to this, when I press the home button and exit the app, I get this in the device console:

```
Tue Nov 24 13:58:56 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.mycompany.MyApplicationName[0x3761]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:2649 (23909):10
Tue Nov 24 13:58:56 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.mycompany.MyApplicationName[0x3761]) Working around 5020256. Assuming the job crashed.
Tue Nov 24 13:58:56 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.mycompany.MyApplicationName[0x3761]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault
Tue Nov 24 13:58:56 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[181] <Warning>: 1 [00b5/1603]: error: ::read ( 7, 0x28091c, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Tue Nov 24 13:58:56 unknown SpringBoard[25] <Warning>: Application 'MyApplicationName' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault
```

I'd be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction or explain what's going on because this is really confusing me!

Many thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `AppleSynopsysOTGDevice` handles the USB connection. This suggest the error lays somewhere in the USB connection/configuration/hardware. The console errors suggest that the app/OS is polling the USB repeatedly but not getting an answer.

If you're running with the iPhone plugged in, I would start by disconnecting see if that resolves the problem. Disconnecting any accessory devices you might have plugged into the iphone.

Comment: Ah thank you, I was using a USB extender! Would never have figured that out!!

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I had problems with my official cable that came with the Blutooth headset from Apple on a new 27" iMac